# iOS: APNS Certificate expires in 30 days - how is this related to APN key in Firebase messaging?

Tags: firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Messaging for iOS and Android push notifications. **I am using the new "APNs Authentication Key" mechanism and not "APN certificate"**

I got an email from Apple that my "Push Certificate" will expire in 30 days and per their help document, I need to switch to this new certificate otherwise push services will stop working for my deployed app in 30 days.

I'm confused on what to do and whether APNS certificate expiring has any relevance to my app that uses APN Keys.

Per Apple's email:
- I've generated the new certificate
- I haven't yet revoked the old one - will do that only after I am sure on what to do
- The predicament is I don't see where to upload to Firebase

Here is my Firebase settings - as you see I don't use the APN certificate.

**So Question: What do I need to do with the renewed certificate?**

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, I waited for more than 30 days.
The answer is "it doesn't affect you if you are using the new APN keys"

Instead of sending an ominous email, I wish they'd also write - this only applies to you if you are not using APN keys.

Comment: I was running into the same issue today. Documentation is severely lacking on this one.  Thanks for answering your own question!

Comment: @user1361529 I'm going to renew my APN certificate too. I had my distribution certificate expired so I created new one. My APN certificate will expire 8th April. Not sure of what I should do, I don't want to delete my actual APNs Authentication Key as this is not clear if it will affect the current build available in AppStore... ty

Answer (score 0):

i'm Also in the exact situation right now, last year another developer created a APNS certificate and it was going to expire by next month 8th. so client got a mail from apple and there mentioned same thing ( your apple push service certificate going to be expire in next 30 Days) and client immediate forward that mail to me and asked to do the needful, i checked there firebase console and inside cloud messaging i found they are using apns key instead of the certificate. ***so now no worries that certificate was created but neither uploaded anywhere nor revoked*** and created panic for client and mine time also. so no worries we learned here something.there is any of push service certificate created but not used, it should be revoked so next person or client will not take any panic from apple's alert Email.