# APNS: is APNS certificate needed if Auth Key using?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm supporting one mobile application. Recently I got email that "apns production certificate will expiring soon". After that I checked my backend and found that no any certs using, only auth key. As I know auth keys don't have expiration key. I suppose that apns-cert used on first time after launch or maybe created mistakenly but not using right now. So I have couple of quesions:

1) For well-working APNS, should I have only auth key without APNS certificates? (My idea here - can I safely remove cert without hurting current APNS)?

2) If for example I have non-used in production APNS certificate - I still receive some notifications on my email - like "this certificate will expiring soon"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868428/ios-apns-certificate-expires-in-30-days-how-is-this-related-to-apn-key-in-fir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) For well-working APNS, should I have only auth key without APNS
>   certificates? (My idea here - can I safely remove cert without hurting
>   current APNS)?

You can safely remove any expired APNS certificate if you are not using. They are not related to the Auth Keys.

> 2) If for example I have non-used in production APNS certificate - I
>   still receive some notifications on my email - like "this certificate
>   will expiring soon"?

Just because you created those certificates, so Apple notifies you of the expiry date whenever they are going to be expired.

You can reference to the following discussion for more details.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/91891